# Как установить макет балуна Карусель с помощью ObjectManager в API Яндекс Карты

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Как с помощью ObjectManager установить и настроить макет «Карусель» для балуна кластера. По умолчанию: Макет балуна кластера "Две колонны". Примеров с ObjectManager не нашёл в документации.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пожалуйста, прочитайте ещё раз [документацию](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/ObjectManager.html) к **ObjectManager**.
В первом же блоке описания опций говорится:

1. Можно задавать все опции, указанные в описании [Clusterer](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/Clusterer.html), за исключением опций **hasBalloon** и **hasHint**.
2. Опции для кластеров задаются с префиксом **cluster** (например **clusterBalloonContentLayout: 'cluster#balloonCarousel'**). Список опций указан в описании класса ClusterPlacemark;

Так что вы можете просто взять все параметры из нужного [примера с каруселью](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/cluster_balloon_carousel) кластеризатора и без изменений добавить в [пример с ObjectManager](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager_balloon) и всё будет работать.